# How to use chromecast without using extension

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, chromecast, google-cast

google cast provides sample github links, which uses default cast extension to cast the data by registering from developer console, but how to use this sender/receiver application without using chrome extension by auto detecting the device and cast the data, is there any specific tutorials to follow up?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a project that uses a similar approach like the one you're asking about and I came across a couple of repo's on github that helped me along the way but there isn't so much on the internet about it.

Basically you can communicate with the Google cast device without relying on the google extension by applying two steps.

1. Discover the device on the local network by using a service discovery service such as Bonjure or MDNS, [here's a sample repo on github that uses a pure JavaScript implementation.](https://github.com/mdns-js/node-mdns-js)
2. Communicate with the Google cast device over the network by using google's CASTV2 protocol over TLS and [here's one of the most popular implementations can be found here on this github repo](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2) and also [here's a high level implementation of the same library](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2-client) these libraries are also in written in JavaScript.